# Push array to a certain hash within an array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, push, hash

I want to dynamically push values of hashes into an array of hashes in Perl.

I have this code block to create and push classHash to an array classList.

```
    $courseName = <STDIN>;
    $section = <STDIN>;

    my $classHash = {};

    $classHash->{courseName} = $courseName;
    $classHash->{section} = $section;
    push @classList, $classHash;
```

Now, I want to add a studentHash to the classHash.

```
    for my $i ( 0 .. $#classList ) {
        #I want to add the studentHash to a specific classHash in the classList
        if($courseName1 eq $classList[$i]{courseName} && $section1 eq $classList[$i]{section}){
             $studName = <STDIN>;
             $studNum = <STDIN>;

             my $studHash = {};

             $studHash->{studName} = $studName;
             $studHash->{studNum} = $studNum;

             push @studList, $studHash;
             push @{$classList[$i]}, \@studList; #but this creates an array reference error
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add $classHash->{students} = []; and then push your $studHash into @{ $classList[$i]->{students} }

Comment: The studList array shall only be stored in an existing classHash (which was created on the first block of code). I don't get why I should add classHash->{students} = [];

Comment: Yes, so you can make room for the students by adding a `students` field to your %classHash, and then add the $studHash to that array.

Comment: maybe provide an example of the data structure you want to have in the end

Comment: It doesn't cause an error anymore, but what it does is add the studHash to all existing classHash. I want to add a studHash to a specific classHash only.

Comment: [1] Add Class
[2] Add Student to Class

When I choose 1, it will create a new class
When I choose 2, it will ask the user to which class would he want the students be added to. It will then loop all the existing classHash in the classList and will see if the input matches the existing classHash. 

If the class exists, the user will be asked to enter the name and number of the student, and will push the input values into the existing classHash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the interactive bits... here is how you can add the student to the class:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

my @classList = (
    {
       courseName => 'Algebra',
       section    => 101,
       students   => [],
    },
    {
       courseName => 'Geometry',
       section    => 102,
       students   => [],
    }, 
 );

my $studName = 'Alice';
my $studNum  = 13579;
my $desiredClass = 'Geometry';
my $desiredSection = 102;

for my $class (@classList) {
    if ($class->{courseName} eq $desiredClass and
        $class->{section}    eq $desiredSection) {
        # Add student to the class
        my $student = {
            studName => $studName,
            studNum  => $studNum,
        };
        push @{ $class->{students} }, $student;
    }
}

print Dumper \@classList;

# Printing out the students for each class
for my $class (@classList) {
    my $course  = $class->{courseName};
    my $section = $class->{courseSection};
    my $students = $class->{students};
    my $total_students = scalar @$students;
    my $names = join ', ', map { $_->{studName} } @$students;

    print "There are $total_students taking $course section $section.\n";
    print "There names are [ $names ]\n";
}
```

**Output**

```
VAR1 = [
      {
        'students' => [],
        'section' => 101,
        'courseName' => 'Algebra'
      },
      {
        'students' => [
                        {
                          'studNum' => 13579,
                          'studName' => 'Alice'
                        }
                      ],
        'section' => 102,
        'courseName' => 'Geometry'
      }
    ];

There are 0 students taking Algebra section 101.
There names are [ ]
There are 1 students taking Geometry section 102.
There names are [ Alice ]
```

Comment: How to access each students in a class? The code works but I don't know how to print the studList per classHash